# FFmpeg compand filter not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I ran the following batch, and didn't get any output:

```
ffmpeg -i e.mkv -af compand=attacks=0:points=-80/-80|-12/-12|20/-12 -vcodec copy r.mp4
```

I'm using [this XP version](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/issues/219#issuecomment-306066471) of FFmpeg.

Comment: I tried "-report" and it didn't work. I think the problem is with the vertical bars.

Comment: Put everything in quotes: `-af "compand=…"` (or perhaps single quotes, not a Windows user, cannot test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling your command from a shell, special characters like slashes, semicolons, or pipes need to be escaped or quoted properly.

So, put the entire filter value in quotes:

```
ffmpeg -i e.mkv -af "compand=attacks=0:points=-80/-80|-12/-12|20/-12" -vcodec copy r.mp4
```